# Overlay Toolbar with a Constraint layout for inApp Notification system

Tags: android, overlay, toolbar, android-constraintlayout

i'm searching a way for overlay the toolbar with a ConstraintLayout but it seems the toolbar have a priority over the ConstraintLayout

[image]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eaecf0"
    tools:context="co.android.yalla.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/Overlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eaecf0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/notification"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grey_pop_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="@string/d_selected_matches"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need to do this for a inApp Notification System
I've tried `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout`
I'm using the theme `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

I don't know if the Toolbar have some specific property about this problem

Thanks

Comment: remove or set elevation android:elevation="0dp" will do the trick.

Comment: ok i'm dumb, i've just need to set a higher elevation than my Toolbar.. ty @vbp